# dk.rb:86:in 'rename': Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails

DevKit Install Error:

```
C:\DevKit>ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/Ruby193new'
dk.rb:86:in `rename': Permission denied - (C:/Ruby193new/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.
1/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb, C:/Ruby193new/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/
rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb.20121026214615) (Errno::EACCES)
        from dk.rb:86:in `update_gem_override'
        from dk.rb:260:in `block (2 levels) in install'
        from dk.rb:246:in `each'
        from dk.rb:246:in `block in install'
        from dk.rb:219:in `each'
        from dk.rb:219:in `install'
        from dk.rb:313:in `run'
        from dk.rb:332:in `'

C:\DevKit>
```

Comment: Your question will need a lot more context to get a good answer - what OS? (Smells like windows but hey...). What instructions are you following to install DevKit? Etc.

Comment: hai! thanks for participating interest: yes your right. It is windows 7 Os 32 bit. I am following this link https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and was able to get around it by running the command-line as Administrator.

Right-click command line -> Run as Administrator. This was on Windows 7 64-bit